# Default constructor in Java

Tags: java, constructor, default

I have a default constructor within my main class that is seemingly not being called at runtime. Here is an example:

```
public class Cat {
    private static int myval;

    Cat() throws IOException {
        this.myval = 7;
        System.out.println("Called constructor");
    }

    public static void main() {
        // Main program
    }
}
```

At runtime I cannot see the "Called constructor" line being output in the window. I'm sure it's something obvious!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you actually ever call the constructor? E.G `Cat cat = new Cat();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors still need to be called in `main`. A default constructor just refers to a class that hasn't defined a constructor. You HAVE defined a constructor, so this is just a no-argument constructor.

Take a look at the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_constructor) article, specifically at Java and C#.

Also, the method you did create needs to be caught since it throws an exception. Your code should be like this:

```
public class Cat {
    private static int myval;

    Cat() throws IOException {
        this.myval = 7;
        System.out.println("Called constructor");
    }

    public static void main() {
        try {
            Cat cat = new Cat()
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // do stuff with e
        }
    }
}
```

A default constructor would look like this:

```
public class Cat { 
    private static int myval;

    public String meow() {
        return "Meow!";
    }
}

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] argsv) {
        Cat cat = new Cat();
        System.out.println(cat.meow());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't have a `main` method.

Yours is `public static void main()`

Try to run it and the compiler will tell you that you don't have `main`.

[image]

Second, you didn't instantiate Cat. Try this revised class and you'll see the output correctly:

```
public class Cat {
    private static int myval;

    Cat() throws IOException {
        this.myval = 7;
        System.out.println("Called constructor");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Cat c = new Cat();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Called constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you never really created an instance of your class did you ?. you have to create an instance of Cat class in your main method.

```
public static void main(){
// Main program
new cat();// this will invoke your constructor call
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Default constructor in Java terminology is generated by the JVM, when no other constructor is present. By writing a constructor, it is no longer the default constructor!

Also, as mentioned, you need to use the `new` keyword to call the `Cat()` constructor.